# DJANGO backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials) returning none

Tags: python, django

I have a weird case:

- I have a custom user model, connected to a sign up form, I do set_password(password) before saving it to the DB, and it does hash with argon2, and saves into the DB correctly. I checked that.
- The check_password(password) works just fine with verifying the username and password.

BUT

```
auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

returns none. When debugging with Pycharm, I see that the username and password are getting passed correctly, but it's failing at this point:

```
backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)
```

bare in mind, that I first get the user from the database to check if present, so the problem is with the password I'm guessing, but can't figure out why.

In addition, 
`login(request, user)` is not working neither.

No exception no nothing, they both just return none.

Can anyone, for the love of coding help me?

Here's the code:

the form:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'first name'
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'username'
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'email'

password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'placeholder': 'password'
}))

class Meta:
    # points the form to the model to use
    model = MyUser
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'username',
        'email',
    ]

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

the sign up view:

```
def signup(request):
context = {}

if request.method == "POST":
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('activate'))

else:
    form = SignUpForm()

response = render(request, 'signup.html', context={'form': form})
return response
```

the sign in view:

```
def signin(request):

form = SignInForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}

if request.method == "POST":
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

    if not get_or_none(MyUser, username=username):
        context['user_not_found_message'] = 'Invalid Credentials - username'

    else:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if not user:
            context['user_not_found_message'] = 'Invalid Credentials - password'
        elif not user.is_active:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('activate'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('landingpage'))

response = render(request, 'signin.html', context=context)
return response
```

get_or_none is a method I created and works just fine, and returns the correct user. I I do user.password it gives me the hashed pass.

Comment: You really do need to actually show that code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I debugged the core Django library and noticed that the code in backends.py is as follow:

```
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
        # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
        UserModel().set_password(password)
    else:
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```

therefore since my user was not active, it wouldn't authenticate